# Way for Java Swing apps automation using .net

Tags: java, .net, swing, automation

Is there any way how I can perform automation of functional testing of Java applets (Swing) applications, using c# (.net)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ranorex to generate C#/VB code. Put that in a separate project. Now, use this created project reference to hit the actions from your automation project in c#.net.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any specific framework for this. However, java gives access for it's Java Accessibility API via Java Access Bridge - unmanaged API. I found a really good project - https://github.com/google/access-bridge-explorer. It is written in c#/winforms and it uses Java Access Bridge. It has wrappers for Java Access Bridge - a good starting point to write c# <-> Java Access Bridge interaction for UI testing. Also, it is similar to Spy or Snoop which is very handy.